# Invoice QTY bug Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, admin, invoice

We have came across a bug in Magento regarding Quantity is not accepting 0.5 on invoic and it is apparently a common issue. https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/23943/files

I have found the solution on git hub but I just need some help regarding this.

I know you should not edit any file in vendor/... but try to overwrite it by put the files under app/... as you can see in the github solution.

My question is, when I have copied all of the files and put them under app/.... as referred in github, do i need to create a registration.php to make it work? and do i need anything else?

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: I've not tried this in M2 yet but you should be able to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39928794/10121426

Comment: Cheers for that, will have a go. 
But i know you should not change the file itself. But will this have any impact if I do as long as i take backups?

Comment: Changing vendor files will make upgrades more difficult